# How to convert wikipedia tables into pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply some statistics to data tables obtained directly from specific internet pages.
This tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-html-tables-with-python-c9baba21059 helped me creating a data frame from a table at the webpage http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all. However, I want to do the same for geographic data, such as population and gdp of several countries.

I found some tables at wikipedia, but it doesn't work quite well and I don't understand why. Here's my code, that follows the above mentioned tutorial:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_African_countries_by_population'


#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)
#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
#Check the length of the first 12 rows
print('Length of first 12 rows')
print ([len(T) for T in tr_elements[:12]])

#Create empty list
col=[]
i=0 #For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    print ('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))
    
    
#Since out first row is the header, data is stored on the second row onwards
for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):
    #T is our j'th row
    T=tr_elements[j]
    
    #If row is not of size 10, the //tr data is not from our table 
    if len(T)!=10:
        break
    
    #i is the index of our column
    i=0
    
    #Iterate through each element of the row
    for t in T.iterchildren():
        data=t.text_content() 
        #Check if row is empty
        if i>0:
        #Convert any numerical value to integers
            try:
                data=int(data)
            except:
                pass
        #Append the data to the empty list of the i'th column
        col[i][1].append(data)
        #Increment i for the next column
        i+=1

print('Data gathering: done!')
print('Column lentgh:')
print([len(C) for (title,C) in col])

Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
df=pd.DataFrame(Dict)

print(df.head())
```

The output is the following:

```
Length of first 12 rows
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
1:"Ranks
"
2:"Countries(or dependent territory)
"
3:"Officialfigure(whereavailable)
"
4:"Date oflast figure
"
5:"Source
"
Data gathering: done!
Column lentgh:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Ranks
, Countries(or dependent territory)
, Officialfigure(whereavailable)
, Date oflast figure
, Source
]
Index: []
```

The length of the columns shouldn't be null. The format is not the same as the one of the tutorial. Any idea of how to make it right? Or maybe another data source that doesn't return this strange output format?

Comment: Long story short: `pd.read_html(url)` gives you a list of tables on the page that you can then index into

Answer (score 1):

The length of your rows, as you've shown by your print statement in line 16 (which corresponds to the first line of your output), is not 10. It is 5. And your code breaks out of the loop in the very first iteration, instead of populating your `col`.

changing this statement:

```
if len(T)!=10:
    break
```

to

```
if len(T)!=5:
    break
```

should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using requests, use pandas to read the url data.

‘df = pd.read_html(url)

Answer (score 0):

On Line 52 you are trying to edit a tuple. This is not possible in Python.

To correct this, use a list instead.

Change line 25 to `col.append([name,[]])`

In addition, when using the break it breaks the for loop, this causes it to have no data inside the array.

When doing these sorts of things you also must look at the html. The table isn't formatting as nice as one would hope. For example, it has a bunch of new lines, and also has the images of the countries flag. You can see [this example of North America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_North_American_countries_by_population) for how the format is different every time.

It seems like you want an easy way to do this.I would look into BeautifulSoup4. I have added a way that I would do this with bs4. You'll have to do some editing to make it look better

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_African_countries_by_population'

column_names = []
data = []
#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)
#Store the html in the soup object
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#Gets the table html
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
#gets the table header
thead = table.find_all('th')
#Puts the header into the column names list. We will use this for the dict keys later
for th in thead:
    column_names.append(th.get_text())

#gets all the rows of the table
rows  = table.find_all('tr')
#I do not take the first how as it is the header
for row in rows[1:]:
    #Creates a list with each index being a different entry in the row. 
    values = [r for r in row]
    #Gets each values that we care about
    rank = values[1].get_text()
    country = values[3].get_text()
    pop = values[5].get_text()
    date = values[7].get_text()
    source = values[9].get_text()
    temp_list = [rank,country,pop,date,source]
    #Creates a dictionary with keys being the column names and the values being temp_list. Appends this to list data
    data.append(dict(zip(column_names, temp_list)))
print(column_names)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```